# Angular client to IIS hosted Entity Framework CORS not allowing response

Tags: angular, entity-framework, iis, cors

Configuration: Angular 6 sends an http request; it is localhost:4200.  The request is to Entity Framework (standard .net) hosted on IIS at port 4000.
It sends a POST to /api/Registration/CreateNew passing the data object in the body.
The controller get functions were tested as non-CORS requests using the browser sending directly to localhost:4000 and they work properly.

The error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/Registration/CreateNew' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: registration:1  It does not have HTTP ok status."

The following is a fiddler snapshot of the headers Request from 4200 (Angular) and the response.

[image]

IIS Entity Framework WebConfig:

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

<add key="allowedCorsOrigins" value="http://localhost:4200" />
<add key="allowedCorsMethods" value="get, post, put, delete, options, batch" />
<add key="allowedCorsHeaders" value="*" />
  </appSettings>
```

App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Also added the class attribute to the Controller Class:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Registration")]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
```

According to the Fiddler Headers shown above, it would appear that CORS requests should be happening.  I have breakpoints on the IIS Controller lines and they never get hit so it would appear this (if I understand it correctly) "pre-flight" request is failing to allow the CORS request.

Unfortunately, this is a sizable chunk of code and hard to put up on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your response error message, it return 404 error, not 401 error.
404 error means he couldn't find the page.

As far as I know, the CORS related error is 401 as like below:

[image]

I suggest you could check your application to make sure you have used to the right url to access web api.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting this.  It took me a while to figure out why the error actually occurred.  Thanks again for your help.